# Is there a logger available to "The Actor DSL" example from Akka doc?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm completely new to the Scala/Akka stack, so please excuse me if this question sounds primitive.  I'm playing with "The Actor DSL" example from the documentation (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#The_Actor_DSL) and am struggling to figure out how to get a logger in there to facilitate my understanding of the sequence of events.  Earlier in the chapter the examples showed how you can get a logger within an Actor's definition simply with...

```
import akka.event.Logging
...
val log = Logging(context.system, this)
```

But when I try this in the REPL all I get is ":15: error: recursive value log needs type".  Here's pretty much the state of my REPL.  The problem is at the bottom...

```
bobk-mbp:akka_hw_scala bobk$ sbt
> set scalacOptions in (Compile, console) += "-Yrepl-sync"
> console
scala> import akka.actor.ActorDSL._
import akka.actor.ActorDSL._

scala> import akka.actor.ActorSystem
ActorSystem       ActorSystemImpl   

scala> import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

scala> implicit val system = ActorSystem("demo")
system: akka.actor.ActorSystem = akka://demo

scala> import akka.event.Logging
import akka.event.Logging

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val a = actor(
  new Act {
    val log = Logging( context.system, this )
    become {
      case "info" => log.info( "A" )
      case "switch" => becomeStacked {
        case "info" => log.info( "B" )
        case "switch" => unbecome()
      }
      case "lobotomize" => unbecome()
    }
  }
)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:15: error: recursive value log needs type
           val log = Logging( context.system, this )
               ^

scala>
```

How can I make a logger available to my ActorDSL defined Actors in a REPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Act with ActorLogging` to get a `log` in your `Act` class.

```
val a = actor(
  new Act with ActorLogging {
    become {
      case "info" => log.info( "A" )
      case "switch" => becomeStacked {
        case "info" => log.info( "B" )
        case "switch" => unbecome()
      }
      case "lobotomize" => unbecome()
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, if I don't try to bind the logger to my val log, it works...

```
val a = actor(
  new Act {
    become {
      case "info" => Logging( context.system, this ).info( "A" )
      case "switch" => becomeStacked {
        case "info" => Logging( context.system, this ).info( "B" )
        case "switch" => unbecome()
      }
      case "lobotomize" => unbecome()
    }
  }
)
```

...hmmm.

Comment: see my answer on the mailing list